# Вставить значение в xml файл

Tags: c#, xml

Здравстуйте. Есть xml-файл.

```
<MenuGroups>
  <MenuGroup RuText="Группа" EnText="Group1">
    <MenuItems>
      <MenuItem RuText="Текст1" Link="Ссылка1" />
    </MenuItems>
    <MenuItems>
      <MenuItem RuText="Текст2" Link="Ссылка2" />
    </MenuItems>
  </MenuGroup>
</MenuGroups>
```

Я вытащил эту xml в документ и создал `XPathNavigator`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);
XPathNavigator navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
```

Как можно заменить значение ссылки? Например первой.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил

Comment: Вам принципиально надо использовать `XmlDocument`/`XPathNavigator`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет не принципиально. Пробую ваш способ, подключил System.Xml.Linq, но всё равно не видит этих методов например Root и всех остальных. Что нужно подключить? Может какую то библиотеку?

Comment: А какой нибудь <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> присутствует?

Comment: @test123 да. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

Comment: Что значит не видит методов? Вы именно `XDocument` создаете? Это не тоже самое, что `XmlDocument`

Comment: @АндрейNOP извините, не заметил, сейчас всё нормально.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а как мне мой документ прогнать теперь в цикле? Что за основу брать, ну по чему гонять то вернее?

Comment: А что вы хотите с ним в цикле делать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну что бы найти нужный мне узел.

Comment: @АндрейNOP `ElementAt(0)` выглядит как то не совсем красиво, а если там ещё узлов прибавиться вначале, менять в коде каждый раз циферку?

Comment: Вы можете использовать Linq в полной мере, например, вместо `.ElementAt(0)` можно написать `.Where(e => e.Attribute("RuText").Value == "Текст1")` (или, наверное, `.First(e => e.Attribute("RuText").Value == "Текст1")`), если вам нужно выбрать элемент с конкретным значением атрибута "RuText"

Comment: А с `XPathNavigator` — да, придется организовывать цикл вручную и проверять элемент, на котором стоит курсор

Comment: @АндрейNOP я может вас немного не правильно понял, вот мой код как я сделал, ошибка на `Element`. `doc.Root.Element("MenuGroup").Elements("MenuItems").Where(s => s.Attribute("RuText").Value == "Акт о браке листа").Element("MenuItem").Attribute("Link").Value = "Новая ссылка";`

Comment: @АндрейNOP что я делаю не так?

Comment: `Where` возвращает перечисление, вам надо брать `Where(...).First()` или сразу `First(...)` с условием

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78179/discussion-between--nop-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью Linq2Xml это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
xdoc.Root // или .Element("MenuGroups")
    .Element("MenuGroup")
    .Elements("MenuItems")
    .First() // или .ElementAt(0)
    .Element("MenuItem")
    .Attribute("Link")
    .Value = "Новая ссылка";
Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
```

Свойство `Root`  в `XDocument` всегда возвращает корневой элемент, метод `Element` возвращает первый найденный элемент с указанным именем, `Elements` возвращает перечисление элементов с указанным именем (или всех элементов, если имя опустить), с помощью Linq берем оттуда нужный элемент. Методы `Attribute`/`Attributes` действуют аналогично методам `Element`/`Elements`, но ищут по атрибутам.

После того, как нужный атрибут (или элемент) найден, можно изменить его свойство `Value`.

---

Использование `XPathNavigator` гораздо менее удобно, ваш код мог бы выглядеть примерно так:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);
navigator.MoveToChild("MenuGroups", "");
navigator.MoveToChild("MenuGroup", "");
navigator.MoveToChild("MenuItems", "");
navigator.MoveToChild("MenuItem", "");
navigator.MoveToAttribute("Link", "");
navigator.SetValue("Новая ссылка");
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Документация по использованию классов `XmlDocument` и `XPathDocument` находится здесь: [Обработка XML-данных с использованием модели данных XPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/data/xml/process-xml-data-using-the-xpath-data-model)